# Google Sheets - Can I call a function that's embedded in an extension from within AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the GPT for Sheets extension by Talarian. This extension works by making custom functions available directly in the sheet's cell like GPT() or GPT_FILL() etc.
Since I am trying to provide quite a bit of data to GPT and in return need text that is several paragraphs long, the response time often exceeds the 30 second maximum that is allowed for custom functions in Google Sheets.

Is there a way to address the e.g. GPT() function that resides in the Talarian extension from within an AppScript (macro), as those execution timeouts are much more generous multi-minute maximums? So could I have a function that is something like
`extensions.Talarian.GPT.GPT()`

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot call a **published** add on's function from your own Apps script.

Comment: Thanks. Worked around it using native AppScript with a much more generous 6 minute timeout.